# Emits in Vue won't emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What I want to do:

I click on button in comments.vue which is suppose to add the comment typed in the text area. This action will get emitted to event.vue which listens for the action. When it hears the action, it will activate a method which pushes the comment into a list. Then I want to display this list of comments. I can't figure out why it won't work.

Comments.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label>Comments</label>
      <textarea v-model="comment"/>
      <input class="button" @click.prevent="addComment" type="submit" value="Add comment">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      name: 'Arnulf',
      comment: ''
      /* timeAndDate: Date */
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addComment () {
      const comment = {
        name: this.name,
        comment: this.comment
        /* timeAndDate: this.timeAndDate */

      }
      console.log('hello')
      this.$emit('submitted', comment)// THIS WONT EMIT FOR SOME REASON

      this.comment = ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Event.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CommentList :comments="listOfComments"></CommentList>
    <Comments @submitted="addComment"></Comments>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CommentList from '@/components/CommentList'
import Comments from '@/components/Comments'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      listOfComments: []
    }
  },
  name: 'Event',
  components: {
    CommentList,
    Comments
  },
  methods: {
    addComment (comment) {
      console.log('bruh')
      this.listOfComments.push(comment)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

commentlist.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Kommentarer:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
        {{comment.name}}:
        <br/>
        "{{comment.comment}}"
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CommentList',
  props: {
    comments: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit: Added the rest of the code, so all logic can be traced.

Comment: Is `listOfComments` reactive? Aka have you defined it in `data`?

Comment: Yes it is defined in data. the console.log('bruh') never hits.

Comment: @Kenso33, I've tried your code in SO code snippets(posted as answer below) as well as [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/). It's working perfectly fine everywhere. It would be better if you can provide some kind of issue reproducible code snippets.

Comment: you are using `vue2` or `vue3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. check the below code snippet.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('root', {
  data () {
    return {
      listOfComments: []
    }
  },
  name: 'Event',
  methods: {
    addComment (comment) {
      console.log('bruh')
      this.listOfComments.push(comment)
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <comments-list :comments="listOfComments"></comments-list>
    <comments @submitted="addComment"></comments>
  </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('comments',{
data () {
    return {
      name: 'Arnulf',
      comment: ''
      /* timeAndDate: Date */
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addComment () {
      const comment = {
        name: this.name,
        comment: this.comment
        /* timeAndDate: this.timeAndDate */

      }
      console.log('hello')
      this.$emit('submitted', comment)// THIS WONT EMIT FOR SOME REASON

      this.comment = ''
    }
  },
  template : `
    <div>
    <form>
      <label>Comments</label>
      <textarea v-model="comment"/>
      <input class="button" @click.prevent="addComment" type="submit" value="Add comment">
    </form>
  </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('comments-list',{
  props: {
    comments: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  template : `
  <div>
    <h3>Kommentarer:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
        {{comment.name}}:
        <br/>
        "{{comment.comment}}"
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `
});

new Vue({ el:"#root" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <root></root>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that my event.vue component was the issue. I was so stuck up on why my code would not work, that I didn't consider that it was just the html that didn't work properly. It is now fixed and fully functional! Thank you!